# PostgreSQL insert select multiple column values

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with three columns:

```
Name Surname NameSuname
Bob  Marley  NULL
John Doe     NULL
```

I want to insert values from `Name` and `Surname` columns into `NameSuname` column. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the coumn instead of inserting

```
UPDATE MyTable
  SET NameSuname = Name || ' ' || Surname
```

Comment: Of course, you combine the 2 by using a trigger that fires after table insert, which will do the update for you, getting you back to the impression that you're only doing an insert. Plus it will be part of the same transaction, thus all fail or all succeed.